# Having Trouble Calculating The Correct Average of 10 Integer Values in C

Tags: c

Hello Stack Community!

I am having trouble calculating the correct average for 10 integers. 
The expected output average is supposed to be 140.0 with one integer value recognized as not a positive program by the compiler.

This is what I have compiled, and it recognized the negative integer but the average still comes to 150.0

Just trying to figure out what I am missing here. 
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    /* variable definition: */
    int count, value, sum;
    double avg;
    /* Initialize */
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    avg = 0.0;
    // Loop through to input values
    while (count < 10)
    {
        printf("Enter a positive Integer\n");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        if (value >= 0) {
            sum = sum + value;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("Value must be positive\n");
        }
    }
     // Calculate avg. Need to type cast since two integers will yield an integer
    avg = (double) sum/count;
    printf("average is %lf\n " , avg );
    return 0;
}
```

Values are: `100 100 100 100 -100 100 200 200 200 200`

Comment: Tip: you don't need to separate local variable declaration from initialization. If you combine the two you will make your code more succint and more readable.

Comment: Appreciate the tip, added the values to the original body for input. They are Values:
100
100
100
100
-100
 100
200
200
200
200

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan No, the `sum/count` operation will use IEEE-754 division because the numerator is `double` (because of the `(double)sum` cast), and in C the `/` operator will use IEEE-754 division if either operand is `float` or `double` even if the other is  an integer value.

Comment: One input is still missing ! You will have to compulsorily give 10 +ve inputs whats the next?

Comment: Consider me officially lost being the amateur learning programming; this is essentially the provided code in my assignment with the test cases. @minigeek would adding an additional positive integer due to the negative be the only way to get to the average required? Again I feel as though I am missing something as the test case only provides 10 integers (including the negative one which i imagine makes it unsigned?).

Comment: Your `count` variable only increases when entering a positive value. At the bottom of your question, you have only entered 9 positive values, yet you test for `count < 10` (0-based), thus the loop still awaits a new value (which we are not shown).

Comment: If you're supposed to take only 10 values (positive or negative) as input, you need an extra counter variable (a simple for loop could replace the while loop). In that case, with the given numbers, the average should be 144.444... (when ignoring the -100).

Comment: @minigeek how would you then check that any 10 numbers (valid or not) have been entered?

Comment: Use another counter to count how many valid inputs are entered. Therefore you can divide the sum to that and not the count you have which can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlexP found the explanation: you must check the return value of `scanf()`, otherwise, you will silently accept input that is not a number and reuse the last converted value.

Also note that the cast in `avg = (double) sum/count;` applies to `sum` and binds stronger than `/`.  It is considered good style to make this more explicit by writing `avg = (double)sum / count;`

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    /* variable definitions */
    int count, value, sum;
    double avg;

    /* Initializations */
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    avg = 0.0;

    // Loop through to input values
    while (count < 10) {
        printf("Enter a positive Integer\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        if (value >= 0) {
            sum = sum + value;
            count = count + 1;
        } else {
            printf("Value must be positive\n");
        }
    }
    // Calculate avg.
    // Need to type cast to force floating point division instead of integer division
    if (count > 0) {
        avg = (double)sum / count;
        printf("average is %f\n", avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to read exactly 10 positive numbers, with `count` from `0` to `9`.
2. After reading `100 100 100 100 -100 100 200 200 200 200` the value of `count` is `9` (because `-100` neither added to the `sum` nor counted), which is less that `10` so the loop is executed one more time.
3. This time `scanf()` fails, so `value` remains unchanged; effectively you are reading another `200`.
4. This is why the sum of the numbers is `1500` and the average `150`.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown; so now understanding that with those input values the count disregards the -100 and treats the loop to an additional value of 200 effectively making the total 1500/10, how would I go about getting it to average 140 without adding an "11th value" including that -100?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (count < 10) { 
    printf("Enter a positive Integer\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &value);
    if (value >= 0) { 
        sum += value;
        count++; 
    }
    else {
        printf("Value must be positive\n"); 
        count++;
    }
}
```

This will increment "count" even if negative integer is inputted.
Thus you will get the desired average.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is what you want to do :

```
int last_known_positive_value = 0;
// Loop through to input values
while (count < 10)
{
    printf("Enter a positive Integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    if (value >= 0) {
        sum = sum + value;
        last_known_positive_value = value;
    }
    else {
        printf("Value must be positive\n");
        sum = sum + last_known_positive_value;
    }
    count = count + 1;
}
```

[check-answer-here](http://ideone.com/YiF9uN)

Comment: This is not what OP wants..here you are talking previous positive value in addition ! Which is coincidence in the ops test case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to approach the problem. **(1)** you can read your values as a string with `fgets` and then call `sscanf` and gain the benefit of a `NULL` return from `fgets` indicating `EOF` and a test of the buffer containing only `'\n'` to indicate a user pressed <kbd>[Enter]</kbd> to signal end of input.

**(2)** you can read the values numerically with `scanf` and then check for `EOF` to indicate end of input, or some other predetermined sentinel.

Regardless of which you choose, the approach is basically the same. **(a)** make a call to the function you are using for input, **(b)** check the RETURN, and **(c)** validate the value input is within the required range, and handle the data.

You get the drift, on all input, *check the return* of your read function and handle any error or `EOF` condition, then *validate* the input is within the expected range.

A quick example using your code and reading numeric values with `scanf` could be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    /* define/initialize variables */
    int count = 0, value = 0, sum = 0;
    double avg = 0.0;

    while (1) {  /* infinite loop to process input */

        int rtn;
        printf ("Enter a positive Integer ([ctrl+d] to quit): ");

        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &value)) != 1) {
            if (rtn == EOF) {   /* always handle user cancellation of input */
                putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up with POSIX line ending */
                break;          /* on to final calculation */
            }
        }

        if (value < 0)  /* check out of range */{
            printf ("Value must be positive\n");
            continue;       /* try again */
        }

        sum = sum + value;  /* compute sum */
        count = count + 1;  /* increment count */
    }

    /* Calculate avg. (typecast to avoid integer division) */
    avg = count > 0 ? (double) sum/count : 0;  /* protect div by zero */
    printf ("\n (%d/%d) => average: %lf\n", sum, count, avg);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sumavg < <(echo "100 100 100 100 -100 100 200 200 200 200")
Enter a positive Integer ([ctrl+d] to quit):
<snip>

 (1300/9) => average: 144.444444
```

One common thread running between all complete examples is to always handle a manual `EOF` generated by the user allowing them to cancel an individual input, or input as a whole (you decide based on your needs). On Linux the manual `EOF` is generated by <kbd>[ctrl+d]</kbd> on windoze <kbd>[ctrl+z]</kbd>.

Look all answers over and let me know if you have any questions related to the above.

Comment: Thank you David, that was a well explained response. Appreciate the breakdown.

Comment: Glad to help. The easiest way you can learn C is to *slow down*. Almost every function in the C library ***returns*** a value. Always validate the function returns (especially where `user input` is involved -- it could be a cat stepping on the keyboard for all you know). If you (1) always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) and do not accept code until all warnings are eliminated, and (2) validate all users input, you will be well on your way to becoming a competent C programmer. Good luck with your coding.